# How to detect an error at the beginning of a pipeline?

Tags: sh, pipeline

In my script I need to work with the exit status of the *non-last* command of a pipeline:

```
 do_real_work 2>&1 | tee real_work.log
```

To my surprise, `$?` contains the exit code of the `tee`. Indeed, the following command:

```
false 2>&1 | tee /dev/null ; echo $?
```

outputs 0. Surprise, because the csh's (almost) equivalent

```
false |& tee /dev/null ; echo $status
```

prints 1.

How do I get the exit code of the *non-last* command of the most recent pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash has `set -o pipefail` which uses the first non-zero exit code (if any) as the exit code of a pipeline.

POSIX shell doesn't have such a feature AFAIK. You could work around that with a different approach:

```
tail -F -n0 real_work.log &
do_real_work > real_work.log 2>&1
kill $!
```

That is, start following the as yet non-existing file before running the command, and kill the process after running the command.